# excel files look different on OSX Desktop w/Parallels

Tags: ms-office, desktop, parallels-desktop

I have two Excel files on my OSX Desktop. One is an alias and it has the double red lines/logo of Parallels, the other does not.  See attached screen shot.

Can anyone tell me why this occurs? I don't think it has to do with one being an alias, as the double red lines have always been there and are visible on most MS files.

Thoughts?

Thx.[image]

Comment: What happens if you double-click on the .xlsx file? Does it open (or try to open) in a Mac application?

Comment: It opens at MS Office-Excel file, fully useable etc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. Shut down your Windows virtual desktop and make sure that Parallels is completely closed (Cmd+Q). Then, double-click on the .xlsx file; does it start Parallels? If you do the same procedure for the .alias file, does that open Parallels?

Answer (score 1):

The double red lines/logo of Parallels appears when the default "Open with..." application is an application that requires Parallels in order to be opened.

Thus, in your case, it would seem that the default "Open with..." application for .alias files is probably Excel for Windows which requires Parallels in order to be opened, while your default "Open with..." application for .xlsx files is some program that works locally on Mac (maybe Excel for Mac or OpenOffice for Mac..).

Comment: Thanks, however, I don't have open office, nor Excel for Mac. All MS Office files within my MBA have the logo on them.